# Azure Powershell Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount failing

Tags: powershell, azure

I am unable to perform the Azure Powershell command `Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`, even though I am executing it under the subscription owner profile. I successfully create keyvault, storage account, and storage account key in the following manner:

```
$KeyVault = New-AzureRmKeyVault `
   -VaultName "<redacted>"  `
   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
   -Location $Location `
   -EnabledForDiskEncryption `
   -EnabledForDeployment `
   -Tag $Tags

$StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount `
   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
   -Name "<redacted>"  `
   -SkuName Standard_LRS `
   -Location $Location `
   -Kind "Storage" `
   -EnableEncryptionService "Blob,File" `
   -Tag $Tags `
   -AssignIdentity

$StorageAccountKey = New-AzureRmStorageAccountKey `
   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
   -Name $StorageAccount.StorageAccountName `
   -KeyName "key1"
```

but trying to manage the storage account key in my key vault fails

```
$KeyVaultManagedStorageAccount = Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount `
   -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName `
   -AccountName $StorageAccount.StorageAccountName `
   -AccountResourceId $StorageAccount.Id `
   -ActiveKeyName "key1" `
   -Tag $Tags
```

This is the error. As I mentioned, I am executing under the subscription owner profile, so how can it not have authorization? Secondly, the "same redacted object Id" identified below does not correspond to any object in my subscription that I can find. I first experienced this problem with Azure Powershell 4.2.1, and have since upgraded to 4.3.0 and still have the problem.

```
Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount : The client '<same redacted object Id>' with object id '<same redacted object Id>' does not have authorization to perform action
'Microsoft.Authorization/permissions/read' over scope
'/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage account name>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization'.
At E:\BitSync\Scripts\Azure\Create-Environment.ps1:129 char:34
+ ... VaultManagedStorageAccount = Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount `
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount], KeyVaultErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.AddAzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount
```

BTW, there does not appear to be any way to manage Storage Account keys through Key Vault in the portal other than cut and paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your error message, it is **a RBAC issue**, the service principal you are using does not have rights within that tenant.

Tenants have subscriptions and service principals belong to tenants. Azure resource manager also exposes role based authorization for a given principal, which would give it rights on Azure resources. It appears the service principal doesn't have rights to read from that subscription.

We can assign RBAC roles at the resource scope via Azure portal, more information about assign RBAC, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-create-custom-roles-for-internal-external-users).

**Note**:
Key vault needs permissions to *list* and *regenerate keys* for a storage account.we can use the following steps to do it:

Get ObjectId of your account:

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Azure Key Vault"
```

Assign Storage Key Operator role to Azure Key Vault Identity:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId <objectId of AzureKeyVault from previous command> -RoleDefinitionName 'Storage Account Key Operator Service Role' -Scope '<azure resource id of storage account>'
```

More information about setup for role-based access control permissions, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys#getting-started).

**Update**:

Also, we should set Azure key vault access policy **permissions to storage**.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'jasonkey01' -ResourceGroupName 'jasontest' -ObjectId '556ca95d-2f50-4acd-b98e-a111b5b41b66' -PermissionsToStorage 'all'
```

Here is the screenshot about my keyvault:

[image]

In this way, we can use your script to add key vault for storage account.

[image]
**Update2:**
I have reproduce this error, the root cause is that we can't grant permission to service principal `Azure Key Vault`.

We can use this command to find object id, same as your error message.

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Azure Key Vault"
```

Then we grant permission to this service principal, use this script:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId '2f6d671f-6c8d-4104-812a-390c5648aed0' -RoleDefinitionName 'Storage Account Key Operator Service Role' -Scope '/subscriptions/53847abb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx/resou
rceGroups/jasonkey/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/jasondisk321'
```

Here is my result:

[image]

**Update3:**
After run `Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`, we should run this command to get secret URI:

```
Set-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition -Service Blob -ResourceType Container,Service -VaultName yourKV  
-AccountName msak01 -Name blobsas1 -Protocol HttpsOnly -ValidityPeriod ([System.Timespan]::FromDays(1)) -Permission Read,List
```

Here is the result:
[image]

[image]

More information about get the secret URI, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys#developer-experience).

Comment: Jason, this not working for me. Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal returns 2 properties that look like they could be the objectId for New-AzureRmRoleAssignment, ApplicationId and Id, but using either one results in error "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ObjectId'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Guid' and try again". They both look like Guids to me.

Comment: @JackFox We can use `get-azurermkeyvault` to get the information, in that output, we can find the object ID, please check the screenshot.

Comment: Jason, fixed a couple of things: 1) its not the ObjectId of keyvault, but rather $KeyVault.AccessPolicies[0].ObjectId. Thanks for pointing that out. 2) And the resource Id of Storage account is actually $StorageAccount.Id. All that is good. And I am back to my original problem. Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount throws error The client 'unrecognized guid' with object id 'unrecognized guid' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/permissions/read' over scope 'resource id of storage account'

Comment: @JackFox Does your account is the owner of this group?

Comment: \@Jason I'm the owner of the subscription. I wonder if AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount works only in Enterprise Azure. Mine is an MSDN subscription. The fact the error message displays a client guid I cannot identify is curious.

Comment: @JackFox  sorry for my mistake.  I had reproduce this error, MSDN subscription works fine. the root cause is we have not grant permission to `Azure Key Vault`, I will update my answer, please check it.

Comment: deleted comment for now

Comment: Jason, with this information I got Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount to work, which is a success, but I expected the storage account key to show up as a key asset in the key vault. Opening the key vault as the owner in the portal does not show me this as either a key or secret asset. Is this key now only accessible by the service principal Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Azure Key Vault"?

Comment: @JackFox No, the `Azure key vault` just belong to your Azure account, this service principal just used for manager key vault, so we can use your Azure account to access this key vault.  Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Jason, yes helpful. Thanks. I'm still trying to figure out why the key does not show up in my key vault after successfully performing Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount. It may take me a couple of days because I am working on other things as well.

Comment: @JackFox This command `Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`  made this storage account managed by key vault. key vault  performs several internal management functions on your behalf when you use Storage Account Keys, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys#storage-account-keys-behavior).  after that we should run this command `Set-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition` to create the secret, I will update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Jason and then Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret to set a value in the secret? Thanks for your help and patience. There is very little literature other than the Azure docs on this topic, and the docs have very little background information for understanding context.

Comment: After making a storage account keys managed by keyvault, isn't it possible to access that storage account from any other application .e.g  Storage Explorer, Cloud Explorer, Power BI  etc.  What happens to the keys displayed in the Azure portal for this storage account ?